# Determine loudness of currently-playing audio in Android

Tags: android

I'm pretty sure this must be possible. Is there a way to find the 'noise produced' by a currently playing sound (MediaPlayer)?

Like in many music editor software you import a song and it does a graphical layout of the song, like a graph with it higher up at louder bits.

There must be a way to do this on Android.

(Not the whole graph thing--just like the noise/decibels currently playing or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot intercept the audio output of another application, if that is what you are asking.